# PCL 1.6 installation on windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, point-cloud-library

I try to install pcl for msvc2015 on windows 7. I download pcl1.6 all-in-one exe file form [here](http://pointclouds.org/downloads/)

Then I have installed it by select "dont add pcl to PATH". I add manually `C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\bin` to Path.

I create a win32 console application on msvc2015. I open project properties,

**C++->General->Additional Include Directories**

C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\include\vtk-5.8
C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\Qhull\include
C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\FLANN\include
C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\Boost\include 
C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\Eigen\include
C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6

**Linker->Genera->Additional Library Directories**

C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\Boost\lib
C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\FLANN\lib
C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\Qhull\lib
C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\VTK\lib\vtk-5.8
C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\lib

**C++->Linker->Input**

> pcl_apps_release.lib pcl_common_release.lib pcl_features_release.lib
>   pcl_filters_release.lib pcl_io_release.lib pcl_io_ply_release.lib
>   pcl_kdtree_release.lib pcl_keypoints_release.lib
>   pcl_octree_release.lib pcl_registration_release.lib
>   pcl_sample_consensus_release.lib pcl_search_release.lib
>   pcl_segmentation_release.lib pcl_surface_release.lib
>   pcl_tracking_release.lib pcl_visualization_release.lib

Compilation message is here :

> pcl::SHOT::rf': USE SHOT352 FOR SHAPE AND SHOT1344 FOR SHAPE+COLOR
>   INSTEAD

It doesn`t work on visual stduio 2015. Do I have to compile from source for msvc2015?

**EDIT**

I has installed all-in-one pcl 1.8 for vs2015. I have some problems about vtk. 
Below line throws errors :

```
pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<pcl::PointXYZ> source_cloud_color_handler(source_cloud, 255, 255, 255);
```

> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static class
>   vtkUnsignedCharArray * __cdecl vtkUnsignedCharArray::New(void)"
>   (?New@vtkUnsignedCharArray@@SAPEAV1@XZ)

**SOLUTION**

I add some vtk lib files under Linker->Input, it works now. Lib files are below :

> vtksys.lib 
>   vtkCommonCore-7.0-gd.lib 
>   vtkCommonDataModel-7.0-gd.lib

Answer (score 0):

If you used the all-in-one installer of PCL 1.6 from pcl website and tried to integrate it in VS 2015, then it wont work (based on my experience).

Either you compile from source (github) and then use cmake to link it to VS 2015 or you use the all-in-one installer for pcl 1.6 with VS 2010/VS 2008.

Recently, PCL 1.8 was released and there do exist some all-in-one installers for VS 2013, and VS 2015. (in case you do not want to compile from source).

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I has installed all-in-one pcl 1.8 for vs2015. I have some problems. I just edited my question text.